# Set dataclass instance attribute through function

Tags: python, python-dataclasses

How can I make this less verbose and more elegenat?

```
@dataclass
class Bla:
   
    number: int
    numberPlusOne = field(init = False)

    def __post_init__(self):
        self.numberPlusOne = self.addOne(self.number)

    def addOne(self, number):
        number += 1
        return number

Bla(10)
Output: Bla(number = 10, numberPlusOne = 11)
```

Do I have to use the post init method?
I am trying something like:

```
@dataclass
class Bla:
   
    number: int
    numberPlusOne int = self.addOne(self.number)

    def addOne(self, number):
        number += 1
        return number
```

But I am getting errors and cannot make it work.

Comment: Is `numberPlusOne` *always* `number` plus 1? I.e., when you change `number`, `numberPlusOne` should change too? Then a `@property` would be very appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

In my option the `__post_init__` method is the best way.
field method has also `default` argument, but it's impossible to assign dynamic value as default value.

```py
def addOne(self, number):
        number += 1
        return number
```

This method could be dangerous because u increment method argument and in some cases you could modify oryginal obj. (https://medium.com/@meghamohan/mutable-and-immutable-side-of-python-c2145cf72747)
maximum simplification ;) just like this:

```py
# add_one is `snake_case` naming style which should be  
# use to name methods, functions, variables and obj. instances
def add_one(self, number: int) -> int: 
    return number+1
```